# Error Undefined index : foreach Codeigniter - Oracle

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, codeigniter, foreach

I have an array `$dtl`:

```
Array
(
    [MODULE_NAME] => Array
        (
            [0] => Daily_Recurring_Grabber
            [1] => Daily_Recurring_Grabber           
        )
    [START_EXECUTION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19-SEP-14
            [1] => 21-SEP-14           
        )
    [FINISHED_EXECUTION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 19-SEP-14
            [1] => 21-SEP-14          
        )
    [NUM_OF_POPULATION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6630
            [1] => 6169
        )
     [SUM_AMOUNT] => Array
        (
            [0] => 397922098.33
            [1] => 360955418.47
        )
)
```

I just want to display the SUM_AMOUNT's values. So i create my **view** like this :

```
if(isset($dtl)){

foreach($dtl as $row){
?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $row['sum_amount']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

But i got an error :

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: SUM_AMOUNT

Filename: pages/v_soaotc_monthly.php
```

This is my **MODEL**

```
$this->pblmig_db = $this->load->database('collprod', true);

        $sql="select * from inh_soa_otc_control
                where module_name like 'Monthly_Accumulator%'
                and finished_execution is not null";

        $stmt = oci_parse($this->pblmig_db->conn_id, $sql);

        oci_execute($stmt);
        $row = oci_fetch_all($stmt, $result);
        oci_free_statement($stmt);
        oci_close($this->pblmig_db->conn_id);
        return $result;
```

Am I miss something in my code? Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

if(count($dtl)>0){

    foreach($dtl['SUM_AMOUNT'] as $row){
?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

For all elements

```
<?php

if(count($dtl)>0){

    foreach($dtl as $index => $dt1_element){
    //[MODULE_NAME] => Array
?>
        <ul>
            <li>Data in <?= $index ?></li>
            <ul>
<?php
        foreach($dt1_element as $row){
        //[0] => Daily_Recurring_Grabber
        //[1] => Daily_Recurring_Grabber
?>
        <!-- Daily_Recurring_Grabber -->
        <li><?= $row ?></li>
<?php
        }
?>
          </ul>
<?php
     }
?>
    </ul>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks victor, it works. May I improve my question? How if I want to display all the field (not only SUM_AMOUNT)? So it's like displaying the data in table form. What foreach should I use? Appreciate for your help

Comment: So it will print only the whole value. How can I identify which value is owned by module_name,sum_amount,etc?

Comment: use a $index in your loop. UPdated answer

Answer (score 0):

`$dtl` is already an array

you can access `SUM_AMOUNT` by `$dtl['SUM_AMOUNT']`

OR get all values by

```
foreach($dtl as $key => $value){
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
</tr>
}
```